# Join and map operations with Apache Spark rdd-s

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I generate a bunch of rdd-s (20~50) from some data which are quite small (10kb to 10mb) and I want to perform some operations on them, mostly join and mapValues. 
Same rdd might be joined several times to other rdds. Rdd-s are cached.

What my best strategy should be? I chain all operations together and it works all right with small number of rdd-s (like 10-20) but Spark seems to be confused when I have more joins (job gets stuck).

Hopefully someone can share some ideas around it.

Thanks!

Comment: Can you show some code? Maybe the job gets stuck because of wrong use in driver actions?

Comment: I'll see tomorrow if I can extract something reasonable. I use the same code/approach with different number of rdd-s I have - works with 10 and doesn't work with 50. I'm testing on a few nodes (5-20) of a cluster.

Comment: It kind of bugs me that heavy lifting works fine (build aggregations from ~several hundreds gb of parquet files down to kb of rdds) but joins not so much. Even collecting all these rdds on a driver node and doing maps there shouldn't be a problem just because of the size. Something doesn't feel right.

Comment: What's the size of your data?

Comment: You really need to provide us with some code, if you want us to help you. Otherwise, the best we can do is guess...